# Can I shorten automatic shut down time from 60s to 5?

Tags: 10.10, configuration, shutdown

Just loaded Ubuntu 10.10 and loaded all updates on a hard drive by itself (without Windows). Would like to change the time for the system to shut down automatically from 60 seconds to 5 seconds, thus just hitting the shutdown icon once and in 5 seconds the system would shut down or give me just enough time to hit the restart button if I wanted to restart. Any way to do it??

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to configure the timeout currently, and in fact the timeout has been removed.  But there is a couple of wishlist bugs to add it back and make it configurable that you might be interested in commenting on:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-session/+bug/623804

and

https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-session/+bug/607575

You shouldn't shutdown a user session with "sudo shutdown -h now" but should instead tell the session you want to shutdown with "gnome-session-save --logout" or if there are programs inhibiting the layout "gnome-session-save --force-logout".

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to do this without editing and compiling the source code. You can, however, shut down immediately through the CLI using the command `sudo shutdown -h now`.

Comment: Shutting down like this will cause the session to be killed instead of saved.  It's generally not a good idea as it can cause data loss.

Comment: Otoh, if you understand the risks and take precautions (ie, close all apps first), it's not a bad method. On my home system, I rarely have anything open besides a screen session and a browser, so as long as my files are saved, power down old school. I also don't run a heavy window manager.

Answer (score 1):

Open dialogs:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> → `/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --logout`

`/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --shutdown`

`/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --restart`

Create your own Shortcuts, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> for shutdown.

Source: [ubuntuusers.de](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/post/3958927/)